# Typescript: Uncaught ReferenceError: Morph is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Morph is not defined
    at sketch (sketch.ts:7)
    at new p5 (sketch.ts:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (sketch.ts:28)
    at c (sketch.ts:28)
    at Function.r.import (sketch.ts:28)
    at sketch.ts:28
```

The [morph.ts](https://github.com/mictadlo/p5-typescript-fuse-box-starter/blob/master/src/morph.ts) is in the same folder as `sketch.ts` and this is [sketch.ts](https://github.com/mictadlo/p5-typescript-fuse-box-starter/blob/master/src/sketch.ts):

```
import 'p5'
import './morph'


var sketch = (p: p5) => {

    const morph = new Morph();

    p.preload = () => {

    }

    p.setup = () => {
        p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
        morph.setup(p);
    }

    p.windowResized = () => {
        p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    }

    p.draw = () => {
        p.background(100);
        morph.draw(p);        
    }
}

var sketchP = new p5(sketch);
```

Why the import of morph.ts does not work. What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import everything as a namespace, the default export, or a specific export. So for example, since your code indicates that Morph is a class, it should be marked as an export class, or the default export. I prefer to not use default exports, so I would make sure Morph is exported where you declare it:

```
export class Morph {
```

Then in your sketch.ts do the following to import the Morph class:

```
import { Morph } from './morph'
```

Comment: How do I post the 2 files without answereing my own question? The files can be found here [morph.ts](https://github.com/mictadlo/p5-typescript-fuse-box-starter/blob/master/src/morph.ts)  [sketch.ts](https://github.com/mictadlo/p5-typescript-fuse-box-starter/blob/master/src/sketch.ts).

Comment: So with these two files you are getting the exact same original error?

Comment: Sorry, I got a different one: ```Uncaught TypeError: morph_1.Morph is not a constructor
    at sketch (sketch.ts:7)
    at new p5 (sketch.ts:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (sketch.ts:28)
    at c (sketch.ts:28)
    at Function.r.import (sketch.ts:28)
    at sketch.ts:28
    at sketch.ts:28```

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do in sketch.ts. You are defining a function object called sketch, then you are passing that function to the constructor for p5. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I try to learn p5.js with typescript and I used this [project](https://github.com/Gaweph/p5-typescript-starter) as foundation. At the moment I do not know why the code has been written this way.